# How to handle paths setup for multi tenant ASP MVC site

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a site that need to support host based Multi Tenancy, and I got this whole part figured out. The issue I have is that I have in the CSS folder a subfolder for every tenant (1,2,3).

```
CSS
    |_ tenant_1
    |_ tenant_2
    |_ tenant_3
    |_ tenant (virtual)
```

in the *tenant_X* folder there are custom css files used for stypling every specific tenant.

My idea was to somehow create a virtual location (tenant) that would be mapped to the tenant's folder and only one additional line of coude would be needed in the _Layout. I am not profound in MVC and so far I know, I think I can get this to work with a custom route.
One other reason for this approach is that the tenants user is not allowed to see that there are other tenants. I have to exclude the possibility to have the user loaded the wrong files.

Is this the right approach? can you suggest any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation to achieve this just by adding 1 line to the _Layout page, could be to get a css file from a controller as text/css.

So assuming that the current tenant ID is available on front-end you could call a method on controller with that id

For example something like this:

```
@Styles.Render(string.Format("/CustomizationController/GetCssForTenant?tenantId={0}", loggedTeanant == null ? (int?) null : loggedTenant.Id))
```

And now create a customization controller with the method as follows

```
public class CustomizationController : Controller
{
    //this will cache cliente side the css file but if the duration expires
    // or the tenantId changes it will be ask for the new file
    [OutputCache(Duration = 43200, VaryByParam = "tenantId")]
    public FileResult GetCssForTenant(int? tenantId)
    {
        var contentType = "text/css";
        //if teanant id is null return empty css file
        if(!tenantID.HasValue)
                return new FileContentResult(new byte[0], contentType);

        //load the real css file here <-
        var result = ...

        //---
        //if having problems with the encoding use this ...
        //System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        //var content = encoding.GetBytes(result);
        //---

        Response.ContentType = contentType;

        return new FileContentResult(result, contentType);
        //return new FileContentResult(content, contentType);
    }
}
```

Hope that this help achieve what you need. Remember that this is a **sketch** of an possible implementation.

**Edit**
If you want to make a quick try of my suggested implementation use this

```
public class CustomizationController : Controller
{
    //this will cache cliente side the css file but if the duration expires
    // or the tenantId changes it will be ask for the new file
    [OutputCache(Duration = 43200, VaryByParam = "tenantId")]
    public FileResult GetCssForTenant(int? tenantId)
    {
        var contentType = "text/css";
        //if teanant id is null return empty css file
        if(!tenantID.HasValue)
                return new FileContentResult(new byte[0], contentType);

        //load the real css file here <-
        var result = Environment.NewLine;

        if(tenantID = 1)
            result "body{ background-color: black !important;}"
        else
            result "body{ background-color: pink !important;}"

        result += Environment.NewLine;

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        var content = encoding.GetBytes(result);

        Response.ContentType = contentType;

        return new FileContentResult(result, contentType);
    }
}
```

And change the _Layout

```
@Styles.Render(string.Format("/CustomizationController/GetCssForTenant?tenantId={0}", 1))
```

Now the background-color of the page should change to black if you send 1 and to pink if you send 2.
You also can see in the network that if you ask 2 time with the same id the status will be 304 this means that the file comes from cache.
If you change the id the status will be 200 that is a not cached response.

If you pass null the css file will come empty so it will fallback to your default css.

Comment: This worked out pretty fine, but in the end I went with a different solution that would solve multiple problems at once. I have overridden the RazorViewEngine and plugged in my own. This way I had absolute full controll over multiple aspects. But still thanks a lot. It's a nice solution